# Why is my Contract taking so long to deploy?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ico

I'm very new to this, just having a play around at the moment.

I've basically copied and pasted the code from someone else and changed a few bits.

On MIST it says deploying contract and has been for 12 hours now.

Here's my contract:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x30ec602bf62971df952d43a316e299708e440cbf

Heres the code I used:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract ForeignToken {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool);
}

contract MyKidsEducationToken {
    address owner = msg.sender;

    bool public purchasingAllowed = false;

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 public totalContribution = 0;
    uint256 public totalBonusTokensIssued = 0;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 0;

    function name() constant returns (string) { return "My Kids Education Token"; }
    function symbol() constant returns (string) { return "MTKE"; }
    function decimals() constant returns (uint8) { return 18; }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256) { return balances[_owner]; }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 short address attack
        if(msg.data.length < (2 * 32) + 4) { revert(); }

        if (_value == 0) { return false; }

        uint256 fromBalance = balances[msg.sender];

        bool sufficientFunds = fromBalance >= _value;
        bool overflowed = balances[_to] + _value < balances[_to];

        if (sufficientFunds && !overflowed) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;

            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 short address attack
        if(msg.data.length < (3 * 32) + 4) { revert(); }

        if (_value == 0) { return false; }

        uint256 fromBalance = balances[_from];
        uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

        bool sufficientFunds = fromBalance <= _value;
        bool sufficientAllowance = allowance <= _value;
        bool overflowed = balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to];

        if (sufficientFunds && sufficientAllowance && !overflowed) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;

            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 spend/approval race condition
        if (_value != 0 && allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0) { return false; }

        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    function enablePurchasing() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) { revert(); }

        purchasingAllowed = true;
    }

    function disablePurchasing() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) { revert(); }

        purchasingAllowed = false;
    }

    function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) returns (bool) {
        if (msg.sender != owner) { revert(); }

        ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);

        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        return token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }

    function getStats() constant returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, bool) {
        return (totalContribution, totalSupply, totalBonusTokensIssued, purchasingAllowed);
    }

    function() payable {
        if (!purchasingAllowed) { revert(); }

        if (msg.value == 0) { return; }

        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        totalContribution += msg.value;

        uint256 tokensIssued = (msg.value * 100);

        if (msg.value >= 10 finney) {
            tokensIssued += totalContribution;

            bytes20 bonusHash = ripemd160(block.coinbase, block.number, block.timestamp);
            if (bonusHash[0] == 0) {
                uint8 bonusMultiplier =
                    ((bonusHash[1] & 0x01 != 0) ? 1 : 0) + ((bonusHash[1] & 0x02 != 0) ? 1 : 0) +
                    ((bonusHash[1] & 0x04 != 0) ? 1 : 0) + ((bonusHash[1] & 0x08 != 0) ? 1 : 0) +
                    ((bonusHash[1] & 0x10 != 0) ? 1 : 0) + ((bonusHash[1] & 0x20 != 0) ? 1 : 0) +
                    ((bonusHash[1] & 0x40 != 0) ? 1 : 0) + ((bonusHash[1] & 0x80 != 0) ? 1 : 0);

                uint256 bonusTokensIssued = (msg.value * 100) * bonusMultiplier;
                tokensIssued += bonusTokensIssued;

                totalBonusTokensIssued += bonusTokensIssued;
            }
        }

        totalSupply += tokensIssued;
        balances[msg.sender] += tokensIssued;

        Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokensIssued);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your contract is successfully deployed. You can see this if you look at the transaction that created the contract: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x402cb533bc0b9af011f9c3aa77f5ac8c97057c7b6c2334182e0d06a289cd6573

A reason that the creation took a long time could be the low gas price you offered. The gas price is an incentive for the miners to mine your transaction. If the price is low, other, higher priced transactions will be more attractive and it can take a while until yours is considered. Normally gas prices are above 20 Gwei. You offered 1 Gwei, you can see it in the transaction.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to change the gas price now the contract has been deployed?

Comment: There is no need to do that. The gas price holds only for the transaction and can be set separately for every new transaction. When you are interacting with the contract in future, you can set a different gas price. So the low gas price of the transaction that was creating the contract will have no effects in future.

Answer (score 1):

Here, when we see the console, we see a message like "creation of inbox pending...". But you can see all functions list in your work, when you click the arrowhead on the far left in created contract instance.